# ¿Hacer un bucle con un Jquery?

Tags: jquery, bucle-for

estoy intentando hacer un bucle For y que en cada fila al precionar el boton mande un alert, pero solo funciona en la primer fila y en las demas no manda el alert

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Jquery</title>       
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
     .button {
      background-color: transparent;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <?php for ($i=0; $i <=10 ; $i++) { ?>
      <tr><td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><button class="button" id="aparecer_fila">+</button>Hola</td></tr>
    <?php } ?>        
</table>       
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#aparecer_fila").click(function(){
        alert("Si sirve");
       }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: cambia tu id="aparecer_fila" por class="aparecer_fila' y en tu javascript por $(".aparecer_fila")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En tu selector $("#aparecer_fila") el # indica que buscara un id, recuerda que los ids deberian de ser unicos eh irrepetibles, asi que al hacerlo a un id, este solo actua sobre el primero. Para tu caso seria mejor que lo pasaras a la clase del atributo.

```
<td><button class="button aparecer_fila">+</button>Hola</td>
```

De modo que tu javascript, puedas hacer referencia a una lista de clases

```
 $(".aparecer_fila").click(function(){
        alert("Si sirve");
   });
```

Y de esta manera el selector actuara sobre todas las clases que se llamen aparecer_fila

Ejemplo de como podrias usarlo:

```js
  $(".aparecer_fila").click(function(){
          var id = this.dataset.target;
          if($("#contenido_oculto_" + id).hasClass("hidden"))
            $("#contenido_oculto_" + id).removeClass("hidden");
          else
            $("#contenido_oculto_" + id).addClass("hidden");
       });
```

```css
  .button {
      background-color: transparent;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .hidden{
      display: none !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Fila</th>
        <th>Botton</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>1</td>
        <td><button class="button aparecer_fila" id="" data-target="1">+</button>Hola</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="contenido_oculto_1" class="hidden"> <td colspan="2"><p> Contenido Oculto 1</p></td></tr>  
      <tr><td>2</td>
        <td><button class="button aparecer_fila" id="" data-target="2">+</button>Hola</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="contenido_oculto_2" class="hidden"> <td colspan="2"><p> Contenido Oculto 2</p></td></tr>
       <tr><td>3</td>
        <td><button class="button aparecer_fila" id="" data-target="3">+</button>Hola</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="contenido_oculto_3" class="hidden"> <td colspan="2"><p> Contenido Oculto 3</p></td></tr>
       <tr><td>4</td>
        <td><button class="button aparecer_fila" id="" data-target="4">+</button>Hola</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="contenido_oculto_4" class="hidden"> <td colspan="2"><p> Contenido Oculto 4</p></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!, una duda extra, con tu respuesta ya me funciona el script, solo que se activan todos, hay manera de que se vaya  activando una fila a la vez dentro del blucle, para ser especificos estoy intentando hacer que aparezca u desvanezca una fila de la tabla con fadeOut  y fadeIN

Comment: dentro del evento, puedes usar this para referenciar al elemento actual que le hizo click, ya con eso, puedes trabajar con los datos, puedes usar $(this) para realizar acciones sobre el elemento actual. Te dejo un ejemplo en la respuesta de como podrias ocultar o mostrar los tr , lo podrias tomar para darte una idea de como aplciarlo a tus necesidades con tu faeOut y fadeIn. no necesariamente dentro de la tabla, claro